# Drools Planner rule profiling

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

we are using Drools Planner 5.4.0.Final.
We want to profile our java application to understand if we can improve performance.
Is there a way to profile how much time a rule needs to be evaluated?
We use a lot of eval(....) and our "average calculate count per second" is nearly 37. Removing all eval(...) our "average calculate count per second" remains the same.

We already profiled the application and we saw most of the time is spent in doMove ... afterVariableChanged(...).

So we suspect some of our rules are inefficient, but we don't understand where is the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A decent average calculate count per second is higher than `1000` (at least), a good one higher than `5000`. Follow these steps in order:

1) First, I strongly recommend to upgrade to to `6.0.0.CR5`. Just **follow [the upgrade recipe](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-distribution/src/main/assembly/filtered-resources/UpgradeFromPreviousVersionRecipe.txt)** which will guide you step by step in a few hours. That alone will double your average calculate count (and potentially far more), due to several improvements (selectors, constraint match system, ...).

2) Open the black box by [enabling logging](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#logging): first DEBUG, then TRACE. The logs can show if the moves are slow (= rules are slow) or the step initialization is slow (= you need JIT selection).

3) Use the [stepLimit benchmark](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e4845) technique to find out which rule(s) are slow.

4) Use the [benchmarker](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#benchmarkingAndTweaking) (if you aren't already) and play with JIT selection, late acceptance, etc. See those topics in the docs.